# Docker: How to extract the Docker image into local system

Tags: linux, docker

I want to extract the Docker image (from Ubuntu server) into my local system (Linux machine).

I run the following command

```
docker exec -it containername_or_ID /bin/bash
```

I am able to view image by using this command, but I am unable to get this image into my local system.

Comment: If you want to get the image on your other machine and don't want to build it again then the ideal way is push the docker image created on your Ubuntu server to docker hub repository. Then you can simply do the `docker pull` to pull the image at any machine.

Answer (score 38):

It depends though on what you're actually asking for. You are talking about extracting the image, but you're referring to an existing container. While jbrownwrld's answer is right in your context, if you want to extract an image, you can use docker save for that.
Identify the image using:

```
docker image ls
mariadb                 10.3-bionic         92744546933d        4 days ago          343MB
```

Then output the tar file (default format):

```
docker save mariadb:10.3-bionic --output mariadb.tar
mkdir mariadb && mv mariadb.tar mariadb && cd mariadb && tar xvf mariadb.tar
```

There are lots of files and folders being extracted, so you had better use another directory. The folders generally correspond to the image layers.

Comment: Using your approach I've found then inside the extracted image there's a `layer.tar` directory which can then be extracted again and then I got the output similar to `docker export`.

Comment: @JurajMartinka, but you don't need to create a container to extract, you can achieve this on plain image.

Comment: The issue with `docker save` is that the saved tar has all layers as separate additional `layer.tar` files inside the tar. Using `docker export` gives you all of them combined together.

Comment: Well, yeah, it depends on what you're looking for. That could be helpful in certain situations.

Answer (score 32):

You can use docker's `export` tool for this. `docker export` will output the contents of a container into a .tar file;

```
$ docker export container_name > output.tar
```

See the docker docs for more information: 
 https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export/

Answer (score 19):

In order to extract image contents without dealing with many layers, a container should be created first. If `docker run` was already run, use that container, otherwise create a stopped container with `docker create`. Then use `docker export` or `docker cp`.

```sh
id=$(docker create image:tag)
docker export $id -o image.tar
docker rm $id
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Run the container

```
docker run imagename
```

Step 2: get container ID

```
docker ps
```

Step 3: copy file from container to local system using container ID

```
docker cp containerID:. localFolderName
```

All your docker container files get extracted to your LocalFolderName