# How to extract project code from docker to local system

Tags: docker

I want to extract my sailsjs project code (From docker) into my local system (Linux machine).

I run the following command

```
docker exec -it containername_or_ID /bin/bash
```

I am able to view my code by using this command. but i am unable to get this code into my local system.

Any Idea to get the code into local system

Comment: mount a local directory to inside of docker and then copy the files into that mount while you are in bash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract the docker image into local system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52272666/how-to-extract-the-docker-image-into-local-system)

Answer (score 10):

Sometimes it's easy to overlook the simplest solutions. You can just copy the code onto your local filesystem with [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/)

```
docker cp containername:/path/to/files /local/path
```

Answer (score 0):

When runs container:

```
docker run -v /hostPathToCode/path:/containerPathToCode
```

The question is how you get source code there, inside container? Container should not have any source code or anything which you possibly need to save after container destroying

p/s docker exec gives possibility just to ssh to the container

Comment: That will generally mount an empty host directory over the content you're interested in in the container.  In many common languages (Python, JavaScript, Ruby, ...) the source code is directly runnable and could be extracted.

Comment: @DavidMazeth source code should be mounted, regarding empty folder check original documentation https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#start-a-service-with-volumes

"If you start a container which creates a new volume, as above, and the container has files or directories in the directory to be mounted the directory’s contents are copied into the volume. The container then mounts and uses the volume, and other containers which use the volume also have access to the pre-populated content."

Answer (score 0):

you can map host folder with docker container with -v option. 
docker run -v /my-app:/my-app

The advantage of docker volume is that you can work on your code on the fly. so there is no need to copy code from host to container or vice-versa